# How to calculate cpu usage, memory usage from the metrics returned by Kubernetes kublet summary endpoint ie., <machine-ip>:10255/stats/summary

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet, heapster

below is the metrics returned by the kubelet summary endpoint

```
"node":{
        "nodeName":"shayeeb-virtualbox",
        "systemContainers":[ ],
        "startTime":"2018-03-05T04:52:39Z",
        "cpu":{
            "time":"2018-03-05T05:06:00Z",
            "usageNanoCores":989865279,
            "usageCoreNanoSeconds":861395314766
        },
        "memory":{
            "time":"2018-03-05T05:06:00Z",
            "availableBytes":697614336,
            "usageBytes":1809657856,
            "workingSetBytes":1378811904,
            "rssBytes":935657472,
            "pageFaults":56928,
            "majorPageFaults":70
        },
        ...
```

the cpu metric is returned in ns but i need to calculate the cpu usage from the above metric and further more I need to calculate the memory usage from the above memory metrics.I am stuck here I couldnt find any details about the above metrics .

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [K8s Managing Compute Resources for Containers/ "Monitoring compute resource usage"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#monitoring-compute-resource-usage):

> The resource usage of a Pod is reported as part of the Pod status.
>
> If **[optional monitoring](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/cluster-monitoring/README.md)** is configured for your cluster, then Pod resource usage can be retrieved from the monitoring system.

That optional monitoring system would be [**`kubernetes/heapster`**](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster), which enables Container Cluster Monitoring and Performance Analysis for Kubernetes (versions v1.0.6 and higher).
It includes... [a lot of metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/overview.md).

Comment: I need to write a custom agent that collects the resource metrics and calculate the usage from the metrics.The api endpoint above is giving me the metrics but i couldnt get more details about them to calculate stats like cpu ,memory,io usage etc..,

Comment: @ShayeebAhmed You will find examples in the source of that project: https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cpu&type=. But the main point of that answer is: you don't have to write an endpoint: heapster *is* an endpoint, already written for you. Deploy it and you are good to go.

Comment: @ShayeebAhmed As an example, see https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/commit/8f19d2a0b9f76a53cec231adbf224778bfad981d

Comment: Thank you @VonC I wanted to know how heapster is calculating these metrics. Is it possible.If so can u please guide me through this.

Comment: @ShayeebAhmed It uses Kubernetes API calls, coded in https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/tree/master/metrics/apis/metrics/v1alpha1

Comment: I think I found the solution for my problem by looking into your references.thank u very much.